How to make a current sensing circuit for oxygen concentrator to generate alarm when no current on cord
The plate on back of my wife's oxygen concentrator reads 120 VAC, 60 Hz, 6 A. It seems like the amps must fluctuate when it sounds like a pump turns on every 7 seconds, but the unit runs constantly. I am not sure what the current fluctuation is.
The oxygen concentration machine tripped breaker on unit and I am unsure why. The company supplying oxygen concentration machine couldn't determine why breaker on unit tripped. I have an audible alarm for no power to unit, this is powered by a 110 VAC outlet. I plug in the alarm, then there is another outlet on the back where I plug the oxygen concentration into. If the power goes out to the outlet, the alarm goes on, but since breaker on unit tripped the piggyback alarm didn't go off. So I want to make a circuit using  current switch to turn on an alarm if current to unit through the cord stops.
I thought if I could put some sort of current sensor on cord and connect to audible alarm it would solve problem. The trouble is that I am a plumber not an electrical engineer. Thank you for any consideration.

I don't know if I understood correctly, so I ask: Does the audible alarm have its own power supply?

I believe it is better to contact the manufacturer of the machine and go for servicing. Yes, of course, you can be able to fix it. I can already see you have suggestions. But the fact is, not every electronic component that we come across may not be medically graded. In case of healthcare products, safety protocols are important.

You might be able to do something like that with off-the-shelf home automation modules and setting up a rule to trigger a mains socket 'on' if the low power state persists for a certain length of time,  but it might be difficult if the oxygen generator has a very low standby power draw. If I recall correctly those devices have a regeneration phase where they draw a lot of power and then are mostly passive. If there are things like fans or pumps that run all the time that might not be an issue, as long as they draw 5 or 10W. There's also the potential issues of wifi reliability, cloud reliability, internet reliability and so on, from a safety point of view.
Obviously you should get the unit serviced immediately if is blowing the breaker.
To do some kind of bespoke solution might be better but we'd need to know what the minimum power consumption is. If you have a consumer device like a Kill-A-Watt (or one of the clones) it would likely be adequate to measure the standby power consumption.
